# How do I download all the albums from Picasa Web to Picasa Desktop?

Tags: picasa

1. I am using Picasa software and Picasa web.
2. There is option to download an album?
3. I want to download *all* albums.
4. How to do that instead of browsing each album and clicking "Download to Picasa"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/ExampleScripts#Picasa) to download them via a script.  You can use the `list-albums` subcommand and then `get` them in a loop.